# Word or phrase that describes something that was very modern at some time in the past

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase that describes something that was very modern in the time being referenced, even though it is clearly not modern now. For example, I am writing about a computer language from the 1970's.

Comment: "The Apple II was very sate-of-the-art when it was released.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from "when it was released." I'm going for something like, "X company used FORTRAN, a <??modern-at-the-time??> language."

Comment: I think Cargill meant "state of the art."

Comment: *cutting-edge* 70's code

Comment: Everything.  Literally, everything was very modern at some time in the past.  You have people assuming you mean technologically advanced.  Is that what you really mean?

Comment: How about "erstwhile cutting-edge"?

Comment: Yes, I am actually writing about programming languages from the 70s. My audience is young IT people who need to realize that this stuff was very modern and exciting at that time. But I am trying to avoid extra clauses. I feel like there's a word or two that can suffice.

Comment: I think you either have to have some variation of "*then state-of-the-art*" or "*now antiquated*"

Comment: Depending on the context this kind of construction might work: *"FORTRAN was the Dart/Go/Scala of it's day"* or "in FORTRAN's day"

Comment: The comments section is not for answers.  If you have an answer then post it as one.

Comment: It's ahead of its contemporaries. Advanced compared to its contemporaries. Developed more recently than its contemporaries. I find "contemporary" a nice word because of its apparent combination of "co-" and "temporal".

Comment: @CandiedOrange: I think he means "at the time in question it was very modern", not "there exists a time at which it (or something like it) was very modern". So it is not true of everything.

Comment: @SteveJessop Anything man-made was new the first time some person created it. So it's not true of everything, but almost anything worth discussing in this context.

Comment: @Barmar: yes. Pencils were new in the 16th century. They were not new in the 1990s. The question is explicitly *not* about "how to describe a thing that was once very modern", such as pencils. It is about "how to describe a thing that, at a particular past time under discussion, was very modern". This thing, the thing actually being asked for as opposed to the thing CandiedOrange incorrectly thought was being asked for, is *not* true of pencils when "the time being referenced" is the 1990s (although perhaps some very specific kind of pencil was). It would be true of pencils for the 1560s.

Comment: None of the answers seem to include the 'at some time in the past' requirement.

Answer (score 22):

[pioneering](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pioneering) (adjective)

> Involving new ideas or methods:

*Company X used FORTRAN, a pioneering programming language [of the 70's].*

'Pioneering' provides, or implies, the context of historical foundation and excitement of the evolving technology of programming languages, FORTRAN in particular, during the 1970's.

Comment: Does not include the 'at some time in the past, even though it is clearly not modern now' requirement, except perhaps connotatively.

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out in comments, *[state-of-the-art](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/state-of-the-art)* is an apt word.

*state-of-the-art* (noun)

> the latest and most sophisticated or advanced stage of a technology, art, or science.

Source: Dictionary.com

**Usage**: X company used FORTRAN, a state-of-the-art language in the 70's

If you are looking for alternatives, then you may consider :

- futuristic
- visionary

*[futuristic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/futuristic?s=t)* (adjective)

> ahead of the times; advanced

**Usage**: X company used FORTRAN, a futuristic programming language

*[visionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/visionary?s=t)* (adjective)

> given to or characterized by fanciful, not presently workable, or unpractical ideas, views, or schemes

**Usage**: X company used FORTRAN, a visionary programming language, which continues to be used for scientific computing

Meaning Source: Dictionary.com

Comment: Totally off-topic, but I was taught FORTRAN IV at university in Australia in 1970-71, so I guess it had been around for a bit by then.  But it was a very straightforward language, and in reality, today's C++ ain't that different at the front end (although I expect the compile is massively improved).

Comment: Does not include the 'at some time in the past, even though it is clearly not modern now' requirement.

Answer (score 4):

***'Innovative'***.  From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> nnovation innovation
>   (ɪnəʊˈveɪʃən)
>   [ad. L. innovātiōn-em, n. of action f. innovāre to innovate: cf. F. innovation (1297 in Hatz.-Darm.).]
>   1. a. The action of innovating; **the introduction of novelties**; the alteration of what is established by the introduction of new elements or forms. Formerly const. of (the thing altered or introduced).

From *'innovate'*:

> innovate innovate, v.
>   (ˈɪnəʊveɪt)
>   [f. L. innovāt-, ppl. stem of innovāre to renew, alter, f. in- (in-2) + novāre to make new, f. novus new. Cf. F. innover (1322 in Godef. Compl.).]
>   2. To bring in (something new) the first time; to introduce as new. Obs. exc. in Comm.
>   *'1548 Udall Erasm. Par. Luke Pref. (R.), If any other do innouate and brynge vp a woorde to me afore not vsed or not hearde, I would not disprayse it. 1592 R. D. Hypnerotomachia 57 b, This..table being taken up..there was presently an other innovated, with a cloth of silke. 1656 Burton's Diary (1828) I. 98 He was tried in the same way for innovating a new religion. 1666 Dryden Pref. Ann. Mirab. Wks. (Globe) 41 Some words which I have innovated..upon his Latin. 1735–8 Bolingbroke On Parties 63 To surrender their old Charters, and accept new ones, under such Limitations and Conditions, as the King thought fit to innovate. 1967 Times Rev. Industry Oct. 86/2 Nylon..was first invented in 1928, but not innovated until 1939. 1972 Physics Bull. Feb. 67/1 (Advt.), We've been innovating electrometer values like these for over 20 years.'*

Comment: Does not include the 'at some time in the past, even though it is clearly not modern now' requirement.

Answer (score 3):

If you rely on a context that has already informed your audience of the particular period, or a context that will make that plain, then

> **avant-garde**, *n.*
>   2. The pioneers or innovators in any art *in a particular period.* Also attrib. or as adj.

["avant-garde | aˈvant-ˌguard, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13610?redirectedFrom=avant-garde (accessed December 11, 2015). Emphasis mine.]

For example (from the comments), without clauses,

> Company X used the avant-garde FORTRAN language.

won't be misunderstood. With a clause,

> Company X used FORTRAN, an avant-garde language.

Comment: Avant-garde has more concoctions of *experimental* to me  - e.g. avant-garde Jazz, where it's never going to be adopted by the mainstream, and is a bit 'out-there' and weird, rather than conjuring images of something "modern".

Comment: I agree ... avant-garde is a very useful term, but I don't think it's applicable to something as utilitarian and as scientific as a computer language.

Comment: @Cargill Depends on the language. Certainly not Fortran, but you might say it about Haskell or Erlang.

Comment: Does not include the 'at some time in the past, even though it is clearly not modern now' requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider **cutting edge**:

> #### cutting edge
>
> the sharp edge of something that is used to cut things
>
> **the newest and most advanced area of activity in an art, science, etc.**

Source http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cutting%20edge

> #### cutting edge
>
> the most ​recent ​stage in the ​development of something: His
>   ​research is at the cutting edge of new ​therapies for ​cancer.
>
> **very ​modern and with all the ​newest ​features: cutting-edge
>   ​design/​technology**

Source http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cutting-edge

Comment: Does not include the 'at some time in the past, even though it is clearly not modern now' requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Company X used FORTRAN, a computer language that was ***the thing*** back in the 70s.

> **the thing**
>
> Also, *the in thing*. Something in style or vogue, the latest trend. The first term dates from the mid-1700s; the second, which uses in in
> the sense of "popular," dates from the mid-1900s. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+thing)

Comment: Does not include the 'at some time in the past, even though it is clearly not modern now' requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ahead of its times` for something **very modern**.

> X company used FORTRAN, a language *well ahead of its time* then."

Answer (score 0):

*Pertinent*

> adjective: relevant or applicable to a particular matter; apposite:
>
> he asked a lot of pertinent questions: relevant, to the point, apposite, appropriate, suitable, fitting, fit, apt, applicable, material, germane, to the purpose, apropos; on-topic; formal ad rem.
>
> ANTONYMS: irrelevant.
>
> src. apple dictionary

Comment: Hi @sullman, welcome to ELU! Your answer would be improved by providing a source/link for your definition. In fact, if the definition is copied from somewhere else rather than being your own words it's required. I've also suggested edits to clear up your formatting a little.

Answer (score 0):

**Novelty**

Usage : Back in the day cellphone was a novelty

Answer (score -1):

**Avante-garde**

> favoring or introducing experimental or unusual ideas.

Often used to describe historical figures or ideas. It doesn't exactly fit the sentence you supplied, but combined with some of the other answers it could be a step in the right direction.

Other suggestions that might spur someone's imagination:

- neoteric
- unprecedented
- unanticipated
- precipitous
- superannuated
- superseded
- anachronistic
- progressivist
- pacesetter
- trailblazer
- forerunner
- trendsetter

Comment: Avante-garde has already been given as an answer.

Comment: Yeah but that was JUST posted a measly 7 years before I posted my comment. (Sorry :( saw the question and had just answered a similar one for myself and wanted to share. Didn't realize SE would be suggesting such old questions. I'll be more careful before posting!)